# Is there a quick method of listing certain elements of a cyclic group?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, group-theory, quadratic-residuosity

I'm studying applied cryptography and stumbled upon the following question to practice the knowledge about Congruence, Groups etc.

"List all Elements $x$, where $x^2 = 2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{31}$

Okay, so the naive approach would be to iterate the group, multiply the element with itself and check if its residue modulo $31$ would be $2$.

So we are searching for every element which has a quadratic residue of $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{31}$.

Is there any "pen and paper" solution to do this, without having to iterate every element? Is there a theorem which could be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a field, you know that the polynomial $x^2-2=0$ may have up to 2 roots, no more. You could use the quadratic formula (since the polynomial ring over a field is an integral domain) but this would require the extraction of a square root. But it is certainly more efficient than checking all elements.

Also if if $a$ in $x^2-a$ is a square then you can factor $(x^2-a)=(x-b)(x+b)$ where $b^2=a.$

Comment: Ah, I see, very interesting! How do I get the polynomial from a Field?

Comment: A polynomial over a field has coefficients from the field and arithmetic is in the field. So in this case you have that $x^2-2$ is equivalent to $x^2+29$ since $-2\equiv 29 \pmod{31}.$